# Scope of variable larger than for loop, why does it not change value?

Tags: c++, debugging, runtime-error

I have the following code:

```
void nLargestPalindrome(double number){
int i = 5; //subtract "1" because array starts at zero
int intermediate = i; //intermediate value - equal to the array index;
double *decimalDigit = new double[i + 1];
    while (0 <= i){ //acquire digits of number
        decimalDigit[i] = (number - fmod(number, pow(10, i))) / pow(10, i);
        cout << "Value of digit place " << i << " is " << decimalDigit[i] << endl;
        number = fmod(number, pow(10, i));
        i--;
    }
```

So I've initialized an array with value equal to the digit place it is in i.e. 979979 ---> dD[5] = 9, dD[4] = 7, etc...

Now I have the following code in the same function:

```
double numberVectorAddition = pow(10, 5)*decimalDigit[0] + pow(10, 4)*decimalDigit[1] + pow(10, 3)*decimalDigit[2] + pow(10, 2)*decimalDigit[3] + pow(10, 1)*decimalDigit[4] + decimalDigit[5];
        for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){ //decreases size of palindrome to the next largest palindrome.
            cout << decimalDigit[0] << decimalDigit[1] << decimalDigit[2] << decimalDigit[3] << decimalDigit[4] << decimalDigit[5] << '\t';
            cout << numberVectorAddition << endl;
            decimalDigit[2]--;
            decimalDigit[3]--;
                if (decimalDigit[2] == 0){
                    cout << decimalDigit[0] << decimalDigit[1] << decimalDigit[2] << decimalDigit[3] << decimalDigit[4] << decimalDigit[5] << '\t';
                    cout << numberVectorAddition << endl; //runtime error??
...
}
}
```

The following output I get when `number = 997799`

```
Value of digit place 5 is 9
Value of digit place 4 is 9
Value of digit place 3 is 7
Value of digit place 2 is 7
Value of digit place 1 is 9
Value of digit place 0 is 9
997799  997799
996699  997799
995599  997799
994499  997799
993399  997799
992299  997799
991199  997799
990099  997799
989989  997799
988889  997799
987789  997799
```

What gives? I sincerely tried looking around in Google for 30 minutes because I've had a series of low-quality questions here before. But I am unsuccessful.

My question: Because numberVectorAddition is larger than the for loop scope, shouldn't the value change for nVA?

Comment: You never change `numberVectorAddition` in the for loop. The only assignment to it is before the loop is entered. Why would it change?

Comment: @Wintermute: I assign a value to nVA. Then I change the contents of nVA, namely the array values. I then call nVA again. Would nVA = nVA fix it?

Comment: The array values are not the "contents" of `nVA`. They're the contents of the array, in a manner of speaking, but they have nothing to do with `nVA` except that they were once used compute a value that was then assigned to `nVA`.

Comment: Can't you narrow this down to a complete, minimal testcase? By doing so you'll almost certainly find your problem. Therefore I'm basically asking you to debug the code..

Comment: You never assigned any new value to `numberVectorAddition` so I don't see why you think it should magically change. And what's this about a runtime error suddenly? Either you get wrong output or you get a runtime error -- which is it?

Comment: Please get used to ranges [0, n) (including the first element, but excluding the last) and do not adjust to [1, n] (including the first element and including the last)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: They're the same thing, by definition. See: Google.

Comment: @DonLarynx: While your snotty comment was vaguely amusing, I am here to inform you that by convention when we say "runtime error" we typically mean something fairly catastrophic that cause your program to cease its execution. That is, the "runtime error" is flagged up by your computer, not by your post-analysis of your program's resultant output.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, professor!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
double numberVectorAddition = pow(10, 5)*decimalDigit[0] + pow(10, 4)*decimalDigit[1] + pow(10, 3)*decimalDigit[2] + pow(10, 2)*decimalDigit[3] + pow(10, 1)*decimalDigit[4] + decimalDigit[5];
```

needs to be placed inside the `for` loop.

```
    for (int q = 0; q < 10; q++){ //decreases size of palindrome to the next largest palindrome.
        double numberVectorAddition = pow(10, 5)*decimalDigit[0] + pow(10, 4)*decimalDigit[1] + pow(10, 3)*decimalDigit[2] + pow(10, 2)*decimalDigit[3] + pow(10, 1)*decimalDigit[4] + decimalDigit[5];
        cout << decimalDigit[0] << decimalDigit[1] << decimalDigit[2] << decimalDigit[3] << decimalDigit[4] << decimalDigit[5] << '\t';
        cout << numberVectorAddition << endl;
        decimalDigit[2]--;
        decimalDigit[3]--;
            if (decimalDigit[2] == 0){
                cout << decimalDigit[0] << decimalDigit[1] << decimalDigit[2] << decimalDigit[3] << decimalDigit[4] << decimalDigit[5] << '\t';
                cout << numberVectorAddition << endl; //runtime error??
        ...
}
```

Otherwise, it is computed once and stays at that value.

Comment: Say I assign nVA = 991199. Then I call for nVA. it gives me said value. I decrease contents of nVA (dD[2]--; dD[3]--;). I don't assign nVA a new value yet because it goes into the "if" statement now. I only call for nVA but it does give me a correct value, **even though I never assigned nVA a new value, only changed its contents.** _Why?_

Comment: @DonLarynx, The value of `numberVectorAddition` does not change automatically if you change the contents of the array `decimalDigit`. When the contents of `decimalDigit`, you have to recompute `numberVectorAddition` to get its value updated. Your last statement does not make sense. That should never happen.

Answer (score 0):

`numberVectorAddition` is not going to magically change on its own, no matter how you initialised it and no matter whether you initialised it using some other variables that may change. Once `numberVectorAddition` gets its value, that's that until *you* assign to it… which, in this code, you never do!